# where download look and feel of windows xp using windows builder in eclipse?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, builder, look-and-feel

I am making a chart in ubuntu for windows interface, so I would like to make it as if working on windows ...

Where download look and feel of windows xp using windows builder in eclipse ??

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

will set the look and feel to that of the OS.

So if you run your program you created in Ubuntu on Windows XP it will look like a native XP application.

You can't set the lookAndFeel to Windows XP if your not running on XP. The whole point of the lookAndFeel is to use the native UI of the OS that's running it.

If you really want to make your application look 'windowsy' on Ubuntu you can create an Synth look and feel. [Here's a detailed tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html).

But personally, I would recommend always using the system lookAndFeel.